# Git config issue and git push error

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-config

I have `--global` git config under `~/.gitconfig`

**has email1**

and

I also have `--local` git config under a git repo's `.git/config`

**has email2**

Both have different emails.

Now when I push to my remote repo from under the repo clone that has --local config I get an error saying ***"remote: Permission to abc/def.git denied to email1."***

Why so and how can I fix this ?

I am using https  github url's so don't have ssh keys set up or added to github.

```
git config --get user.email
```

shows **email2** when run under the clone of remote repo.

shows **email1** when run from my ubuntu home directory

```
git config --get-all user.email
```

shows both **email1** and **email2** when run under the clone of remote repo.

shows **email1** when run from my ubuntu home directory

Comment: Which email does `git config --get user.email` show? what about `git config --get-all user.email`?

Comment: @llion Post updated with answer to your question.

Comment: Does `git config --get github.user` show anything? Do you know if you have a credential helper setup? Heck maybe just do `git config -l` and see what turns up.

Comment: Yes you are right. After I invalidated the credential helper cache, things started working fine. I just figured this out myself. If you make an answer out of your comment I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you have credentials stored in your credential helper. You should try invalidating them. You can also review all your current config settings with the command:

```
git config -l
```